# Adding a space between words after multiplying 2 df columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data frame looks like that:

```
column 1 | column 2
apple    | 3
banana   | 4
carrot   | 1
```

Using

```
print df["column 1"] * df["column 2"] 

returns
appleappleapple
bananabananabananabanana
carrot
```

however I want the words to be spaced out i.e.

```
apple apple apple
banana banana banana banana
carrot
```

Probably really basic but how can this be done? Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just for display purposes this'll work (with an invisible trailing space):

```
print((df["column 1"] + ' ') * df["column 2"])
```

If you really don't want the final trailing space, I'd recommend using `.apply` with a custom function instead, but if it's just for display it's overkill.

Answer (score 1):

```
print (df["column 1"] * df["column 2"],sep=" ")
```

`sep` parameter of `print` function allows you to whatever you want put between arguments. In this case it's a gap.

If you use Python 2x version, as @dazedconfused mentioned, you have to import `from __future__ import print_function` to use sep parameter.

Comment: It seems that OP is using Python2 by looking at the `print` in his question; this doesn't work unless OP does `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: Also, if you do `print("test", "test", sep=' ')`, you would get "test test", while `print("test" * 2, sep=' ')` still gives "testtest"

Comment: @dazedconfused That's a different case. You could do that with `print("test " * 2)`. Question is different. In this case `column1` is not a string

Comment: It looks like OP is using a dictionary to access the contents in column1 and column2, I think it's similar to `"test" * 2`

Comment: @dazedconfused Well better if OP makes a comment and we could see is this ok or not. OP looks like afk.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.6 and am pulling the columns' contents from a csv file. The first line reads `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')`. Tried the code @sacma suggested but the spacing still doesn't show. @dazedconfused